# Multiple Images for iOS app's Background

Tags: iphone, ios, background-image

I have seen different apps that the image will change each time the app is opened on the view background.  How is this accomplished?

Comment: What do you mean by "the app is opened on the view background"?  It's not possible to change the launch images after the app is installed.  Do you mean something else?  Can you give an example of an application that does what you want?

Comment: The image of the view background changes each time app is opened.  FHU Mobile is one that does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add background_0.png, background_1.png, background_2.png, background_3.png etc to your project.

`#define max_image_number 3`

Add the following to your viewDidLoad method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {  
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self updatedBackgroundImage];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateBackgroundImage) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}

-(void) updateBackgroundImage{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (![defaults integerForKey:@"imageNumber"]) {
                [defaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"imageNumber"];
            }

            int i = [defaults integerForKey:@"imageNumber"];

            myUIimageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"background_%d.png",i]];
            i++;

            if (i > max_image_number) {
                [defaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"imageNumber"];

           }else{
                [defaults setInteger:i forKey:@"imageNumber"];
            }
    ...

    }
```

The above will update the image when the viewController is first loaded and also when it returns from running in the background. I assume this is what was missing for you :).

Remember to stop listening for the notification in the viewDidUnload method and you should be  set.

Comment: Why the did this get marked down. Answers the question in detail

Comment: Not sure...wasn't me that voted it down...probably by Jim or Teodor as they are still stuck not understanding the question.

Comment: Is the answer you were looking for? Please accept if it is. If it's not then also say way and I will try and fix it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to included returning from the background

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are seeing is the cached screenshot the iOS system is making of your app just before it puts it into the background.

This is handled automatically, and you do have the opportunity to intercept this.

Check out this answer, you can put an image over your app just as it's entering the background, this will be cached and used to relaunch the app.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshots in the App Store of the application you mention, it looks like there's just a `UIImageView` at the back of the view hierarchy for the main menu.  You can change this by assigning a `UIImage` object to its `image` property.

Comment: Yes, I know how to set a background image.  However, their background image will change periodically

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking.  If you know how to change the image, then what's stopping you from changing it?

Comment: @TeodorCarstea your comment will be flagged for being useless.  In the app, after you download it, it will show one image as the background of the tab bar controller.  A little later, you might launch the app again, and now the background is different.  That is what I am trying to do, not just change it one time and resubmit the binary

Comment: But if you know how to change the background programmatically, then what's stopping you from changing it?  What is the bit you are stuck with?

Comment: I don't know how many ways to answer the same question.  I am stuck at getting the background to rotate between SEVERAL different pics.  Open it one time and background is one image, open it next time, and it is a different image.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to change one or more view's background images, depending on the application launch.

Save an `int x = 0` into NSUserDefaults. On each application launch increment it by 1. When you are to present a view, check that int and set a background image like this:

```
switch(x%3){// %3 just to make it a bit random
   case 0://set this image; 
         break;
   case 1://set that image
         break;
      //and so on
}
```